# Custom UIView retained in memory

Tags: swift, memory-management

I am having an annoying memory issue with a custom UIView when trying to add it as a tableView footer in a VC. Here is what I do:

- I declare a custom UIView class called tableViewHeader. My footer is supposed to display a logo and some text, so it has 2 global variables (a UIImage View & a TextView) and one init method to initialize this  UIView class (i.e., by adding the two subViews and set some constraints).
- In my VC, in the TableView's footerForSection method I declare a new tableViewFooter variable, set the sub-views (attach my PNG, etc.)
  and return that view.

The code works fine to display the footer but it wrecks havoc on my memory - the moment I run my app and open the VC that contains that tableViewHeader my memory jumps by ~20MB (~ 20% jump) and doesn't get released once my VC is released (I checked, the VC itself gets correctly de-initialized but it doesn't show any drop in memory).

I tested a few things:

- Without adding that footerView and opening/ closing the VC doesn't show that 20MB jump, so I am fairly sure that this is caused by this custom tableViewHeader...
- I also checked to make sure the UIImage I load from my Assets is not too large but it's only 200Kb. On top the problem is more the fact that the memory doesn't get released after my VC gets released...
- I've tried declaring my variables (the tableViewFooter variable and the sub-views within that new class) but that leaves my variables as nil when I try to add them as sub-views...

I am running out of ideas as to what the culprit is/ how to fix it so any help you could give me would be really highly appreciated!

My code is below - thanks in advance!
Francois

**My TableFooterView class:**

```
class MessageTableFooterView: UIView {

var shouldUpdateConstraints = true

var logoView: UIImageView!
var explanationTextView: UITextView!
var addFriendBtn: UIButton!

override init(frame: CGRect){
    super.init(frame: frame)

    logoView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect.zero)
    logoView?.autoSetDimension(.height, toSize: 145)
    logoView?.autoSetDimension(.width, toSize: 145)        
    self.addSubview(logoView)

    explanationTextView = UITextView(frame: CGRect.zero)
    explanationTextView?.isEditable = false
    explanationTextView?.isSelectable = false
    explanationTextView?.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 17)
    explanationTextView?.textColor = .darkGray
    explanationTextView?.textAlignment = .center

    self.addSubview(explanationTextView)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

**My tableView viewForFooter Method:**

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    if MessageService.instance.savedMsgs.count > 0 {
        return nil
    } else {
        let headerView = MessageTableFooterView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        headerView.logoView.image = UIImage(named: "savedMessagesIcon")
        headerView.explanationTextView?.text = "Blablabla"
        return headerView
    }
}
```

Comment: Confusing: headerForSection? viewForFooterInSection? Header or footer? Also, how many sections do you have?

Comment: Well the issue is you're allocating a new MessageTableFooterView every time the tableview is calling viewForFooterInSection. Depending on your use case you have a few options. If you have a static table you can create and manage instances of these objects within your class. If you need a dynamic number of footers depending on tableview content try [register(_:forHeaderFooterView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614964-register) and [dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614975-dequeuereusableheaderfooterview)

Comment: Also note that in the viewForFooterInSection you are creating a new UIImage and string for the text everytime, if this is not necessary per message you should cache them within your class.

Comment: *"Without adding that headerView and opening/ closing the VC doesn't show that 20MB jump, so I am fairly sure that this is caused by this custom tableViewHeader..."* And yet all the code you posted is about the footer?

Comment: Thanks all - good catch re mention of footer and header. I edited my post to consistently refer to the footer now.

Also I have a single footer per tableview (one section only) with a static data source, so I don't think that the issue is that my tableview calls viewForFooterInSection multiple times (and instantiates multiple objects)...

Comment: Unfortunately I still don't see anything that would cause this. It would be relatively easy to track down your 20MB using Instruments, so why not try that?

Comment: Are you sure, that the view is not released? Can you add `deinit` to `TableFooterView`, and check that it is actually retained? I think the memory consumption of the app can differ from total retained objects. Like the app got memory then hold it for some performance optimizations, so it can be immediately used after. But I just guessing

Comment: Thanks guys! I followed your reco - it does de-init itself confirmed both through de-init command/ memory debugger. I also found out that my PNG was small (<200KB) but large in pixel (1080x 650) and dropping it to a smaller res limited greatly the allocated memory (more like ~3MB now) - likely because pixels count is what matters for processing... That being said I still don't see my memory getting released. I suspect a memory optimization where my asset loaded in memory only when first needed or the memory is retained after deinit as a precautious... Any insights on memory mgmt welcome!